# Why do Java IoC frameworks favour annotation-based injections?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've looked at several frameworks, including Spring, Guice and Dagger and they all require some form of annotation to mark the injectable field/arg/property/constructor.

For example, given a class with injected dependencies, those injection points must be marked with @Inject to allow the IoC container to do its magic:

```
public class ClassA  {     
  @Inject
  public ClassB objectB;      
  @Inject
  public ClassA(ClassC objectC) {...}
}
```

This seems wrong to me because the class is already aware that the object is being injected.

The cleaner version of this is simply:

```
public class ClassA  {
  public ClassB objectB;
  public ClassA(ClassC objectC) {...}
}
```

The @Inject isn't actually required to consume the object...

- those dependencies can be manually injected without an IoC container (which is exactly what I do for my unit tests)
- Java reflection provides the capability to identify and instantiate the appropriate objects without the use of annotations

So, why do our frameworks require us to break such a clean, neat abstraction by forcing us to make our injection-receiving classes aware of the fact an IoC manager is around?

If anyone can shed some light it would be most appreciated.

Comment: In case you have fields that the container shouldn't touch.

Comment: IoC only inject your object when program actually needs it.. It is totally different than reflection. If you have complete idea about how this IoC Works . Your confusion will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Dagger (at least the Google version) generates DI-related code - it uses code generators rather than runtime class scanning, so this approach is most likely limited and requires compile-time annotations. And even if it could avoid most annotations, there's still the issue of marking which fields should actually be injected.

Consider this pseudo-code example:

```
class Component {
  @Inject Value value;
  @Inject("propertyName") String property;
  Type someHelperValue;
}
```

In this case, a `Value` instance would be injected into `value` (a singleton or a value created by the default provider). `property` would be filled with a selected property mapped to the chosen name. `someHelperValue` would be left untouched.

Now consider this:

```
class Component {
  Value value;
  String property;
  Type someHelperValue;
}
```

If the injector would be implemented without annotation use, `Value` instance would probably be correctly injected. However, the problems would start when analyzing the other two fields. What should we do when field type is ambiguous (multiple `String` properties) or unavailable in context (no singleton/provider of `Type`)? Should we simply ignore it or throw an exception?

Of course, this could be resolved by using existing Java mechanisms, like keywords (`transient`) to mark ignored fields and field names to resolve conflicts. For example, if injector was implemented correctly, this could work as expected:

```
class Component {
  Value value;
  String propertyName;
  transient Type someHelperValue;
}
```

`propertyName` would be filled with `String` mapped to `propertyName` in context, while `someHelperValue` would be ignored. The more I think about, this could actually work - but it still does not change the fact that it's less powerful (no additional parameters from annotations) and more prone to refactoring (if you change `propertyName` key to `preferenceName`, the field would no longer be filled correctly).

It's always nice to be able to pass more parameters to make the injector more robust, and there's only so much you could do with fields names, types and flags. Annotations are simply an easy way of passing these additional informations - although, to be honest, they *do* seem rather verbose.

(However, you *did* inspire me to try out this no-annotations approach, so I might just implement a simple DI framework to see how it works.)

Comment: your UEDI repo is useful - it's much more complete than the proof-of-concept I worked on before posting the question and is a public proof that it's achievable.